# Replacing all values with the key 'value' in a file

Tags: xcode, dictionary, key

I have a file with keys and values as strings and I want to replace all values of every key with what's the value of the key, for example, currently the file is like this:

"key1" = "value1" 
"key2" = "something else"

What i want to do is replace every value with it's very own key:

"key1" = "key1" 
"key2" = "key2"

Since the file is quite large (4k lines), is there a shortcut I can use to do the replacements? I use xCode and Swift (if there's something I can do using these tools).

Comment: Use Xcode or any decent text editor that supports regular expressions when doing Find & Replace. Something like this should work in Xcode, Find: `^(.*) = .*` Replace: `$1 = $1`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson works great, thanks!